# Referencing the values in pointers to arrays (c)

Tags: c, arrays, reference

Note: Fixed (decription at bottom)

For some reason the following code:

```
(*p_to_array)[m_p->number_of_match_positions] = (*p_to_temp_array)[k];
```

where the types are:

```
match_pos_t (*p_to_array)[];
match_pos_t (*p_to_temp_array)[];
int number_of_match_positions;
int k;
```

BTW: match_pos_t is a struct:

```
typedef struct match_pos
{
   char* string;
   long match_position;
}match_pos_t;
```

causes a 'syntax error before '(' error'
This error does not occur if this code replaced with other code.

Could someone give me an idea of why this is causing a syntax error, and how I should fix this problem?

Entire relevant code:

```
 typedef struct match_pos
{
    char* string;
    long match_position;
}match_pos_t;

typedef struct match_positions
{
    int number_of_match_positions;
    match_pos_t (*match_positions)[];
}match_positions_t;


typedef struct search_terms
{
    int number_of_search_terms;
    char* search_terms[];
}search_terms_t;

int BMH_string_search(char* search_string, char* file_string, match_positions_t* match_positions)
{
    return 0;
}



int determine_match_pos(search_terms_t** s_terms, char* file, match_positions_t* m_p)
{
    int i,j,k;
    match_positions_t* temp_m_p;

    i=0;
    /* s_terms is a null terminated data structure */
    while((*s_terms+i) != NULL)
    {
        for(j=0; j<(*s_terms+i)->number_of_search_terms; j++)
        {
            /* search for the string positions */
            BMH_string_search((*s_terms+i)->search_terms[j], file, temp_m_p);
            /* load out search positions into the return array */
            if(temp_m_p->number_of_match_positions != 0)
            {
                int total_m_ps = m_p->number_of_match_positions + temp_m_p->number_of_match_positions;
                m_p->match_positions = (match_pos_t (*)[])realloc(m_p->match_positions, sizeof(match_pos_t)*total_m_ps);

                k = 0;
                for( ; m_p->number_of_match_positions<total_m_ps; m_p->number_of_match_positions++)
                {
                    (*(m_p->match_positions))[m_p->number_of_match_positions] = (*(temp_m_p->match_positions))[k];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            free(temp_m_p);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It appears I have been rather stupid.  An extra set of parenthesis around the values being referenced does the trick (question code has been updated with fix):
Original:

```
(m_p->*match_positions)[m_p->number_of_match_positions] = (temp_m_p->*match_positions)[k];
```

Fixed:

```
(*(m_p->match_positions))[m_p->number_of_match_positions] = (*(temp_m_p->match_positions))[k];
```

If anyone has an explanation, though, about why the first is incorrect, rather than the second, it would be nice to hear though, as I thought that

```
object->*object2
```

was the same as

```
*(object->object2)
```

Is this correct or is there some c definitions that I am missing out on here?

Comment: There are many possible explanations. Try http://sscce.org for guidance for getting better answers.

Comment: Please show the whole code.

Comment: How are you getting around the error at line 10: `error: array type has incomplete element type` (given by GCC 4.7.1)?

Comment: `struct match_pos_t` should be either `struct match_pos` or `match_pos_t`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, code update with match_pos_t, no struct

Comment: Jonathan, I'm not getting that error on the version of gcc that I am using (3.6, I think, I am not completely sure, because I have to run my code on someone else's solaris server)

Comment: In C, `my_struct->` and `my_struct.` must be followed by a field name (you can't put an address/value here). The right syntax `*(object->object2)` can be understood as: 
Dereference the adresse which is in (get _object_'s field named _object2_).

Comment: There is a `->*` operator in C++, but it does something completely different (see [Implementing operator->* for Smart Pointers](http://aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that `object->*object2` was the same as `*(object->object2)`

No, in C, the `.` and `->` operators expect an identifier as their right operand. The `.*` and `->*` operators don't exist in C, you have to spell out `*(structure.member)` or `*(structure_ptr->member)` manually.